# Download Image from webpage without using <a> attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I download a dynamically created image from backend without using `<a>` attribute?  I want to download the QR code generated.

JS file:

```
      var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea"),
  content = document.getElementById("content");

    var data = encodeURIComponent(textarea.value),
      size = document.getElementById("size").value,
      chart = "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=" + size + 
      "x" + size + "&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|0&chl=" + data;
    if (data === "") {
      alert("Please enter a valid data!");
      textarea.focus();
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "";
      document.getElementById("qrcode").src = chart;
         }

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {

    }
  });
```

HTML code:

```
                <p>Enter an URL or some text bellow and hit the Generate button (
                <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+
                <kbd>Enter</kbd>)!</p>
            <textarea id="textarea" autofocus></textarea>
            <label for="size">Size (px):</label>
            <input id="size" type="number" value="150" min="50" 
      max="500" step="50">
            <button onclick="App.genQRcode()">Generate</button>
            <div id="content" style="display: none;">
                <p><img id="qrcode" src="" /></p>
            </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand your question.  What do you mean by *using <a> attribute*?

Comment: Maybe trying looking into window.onload to call the genQRcode function

Comment: You need to use the `download` attribute for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you will need to use an a tag. What you can do is create an a tag dynamically in JS, add href to image then trigger a click?

```
var thisLink = document.createElement("a"),
    thisLink.id = "generatedQRCode",
    thisLink.href= document.getElementById("qrcode").src,
    thisLink.download = "download";

    document.body.appendChild(thisLink);

    document.getElementById("generatedQRCode").click();
    document.getElementById("generatedQRCode").remove();
```