# How to download a file given a relative file path (Angular)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, download

This is my html:

```
<button class="btn" (click)="generatePdf()">PDF</button>
```

When the button is clicked, generatePdf generates the relative url (/var/folders...) for the pdf. How do I download this file from the relative url?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534544/download-image-from-webpage-without-using-a-attribute

Answer (score 0):

.
Hi Beatrice,

To setup a download on your website, you would add an `<a>` tag with the href attribute set to the path to your PDF that you want to download.

```
<!-- Uploaded file in same location as HTML file -->
<a href="examplefile.pdf" download>Link text</a>
```

I hope that this was able to help!

phylo

Comment: I'm generating the relative path dynamically. This answer doesn't work as you can't call a function from href (ie. you can't do href ="generatePdf()").